# Why does ETOPS not apply to older 4 engine aircraft?

Tags: faa-regulations, aircraft-maintenance, aircraft-certification, boeing-747, etops

*This is a follow-up to my previous question: [What is ETOPS and how does it work?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15728/what-is-etops-and-how-does-it-work) 
There is a related question [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8462/are-four-engined-airplanes-subject-to-etops-equivalent-rules), but it does not specifically answer this new question.*

Facts:

- Since February 2015, all new aircraft are required to get ETOPS
  approval to fly ETOPS 180+ routes. [Source](http://boeing.mediaroom.com/2015-03-18-Boeing-747-8-Intercontinental-Receives-FAA-Approval-for-330-Minute-ETOPS).
- The 747-8 has ETOPS 330. The 787 has ETOPS 330. The A350 has ETOPS
  370.

Why does ETOPS not apply to the 747-400?

Comment: Perhaps with the ever-increasing range of new aircraft it became more relevant...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's because the last 747-400 was built in 2009.

> **[§121.162   ETOPS Type Design Approval Basis.](http://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/CFR-2009-title14-vol3/xml/CFR-2009-title14-vol3-sec121-162.xml)**
>
> **Except for a passenger-carrying airplane with more than two engines manufactured prior to February 17, 2015** and except for a two-engine
>   airplane that, when used in ETOPS, is only used for ETOPS of 75
>   minutes or less, no certificate holder may conduct ETOPS unless the
>   airplane has been type design approved for ETOPS and each airplane
>   used in ETOPS complies with its CMP document as follows:
>
> (a) For a two-engine airplane, that is of the same model
>   airplane-engine combination that received FAA approval for ETOPS up to
>   180 minutes prior to February 15, 2007, the CMP document for that
>   model airplane-engine combination in effect on February 14, 2007.
>
> (b) For a two-engine airplane, that is not of the same model
>   airplane-engine combination that received FAA approval for ETOPS up to
>   180 minutes before February 15, 2007, the CMP document for that new
>   model airplane-engine combination issued in accordance with
>   §25.3(b)(1) of this chapter.
>
> (c) For a two-engine airplane approved for ETOPS beyond 180 minutes,
>   the CMP document for that model airplane-engine combination issued in
>   accordance with §25.3(b)(2) of this chapter.
>
> (d) **For an airplane with more than 2 engines manufactured on or
>   after February 17, 2015**, the CMP document for that model
>   airplane-engine combination issued in accordance with §25.3(c) of this
>   chapter.
>
> **§25.3   Special provisions for ETOPS type design approvals.**
>
> (a) Applicability. This section applies to an applicant for ETOPS type
>   design approval of an airplane:
>
> (1) That has an existing type certificate on February 15, 2007; or
>
> (2) For which an application for an original type certificate was
>   submitted before February 15, 2007.
>
> (b) Airplanes with two engines. (1) For ETOPS type design approval of
>   an airplane up to and including 180 minutes, an applicant must comply
>   with §25.1535, except that it need not comply with the following
>   provisions of Appendix K, K25.1.4, of this part:
>
> (i) K25.1.4(a), fuel system pressure and flow requirements;
>
> (ii) K25.1.4(a)(3), low fuel alerting; and
>
> (iii) K25.1.4(c), engine oil tank design.
>
> (2) For ETOPS type design approval of an airplane beyond 180 minutes
>   an applicant must comply with §25.1535.
>
> (c) **Airplanes with more than two engines. An applicant for ETOPS
>   type design approval must comply with §25.1535 for an airplane
>   manufactured on or after February 17, 2015, except that, for an
>   airplane configured for a three person flight crew, the applicant need
>   not comply with Appendix K, K25.1.4(a)(3), of this part, low fuel
>   alerting.**

Comment: Very interesting. That also means that the 747-8s built before February 17, 2015 are not required to comply with ETOPS. They must be slightly more valuable (than they would have been) as a result.

Comment: In a lot of safety regulations (not just aviation) there is a concept of "grandfathering". Regulators want to tighten safety regulations but they feel that doing so for exiting vehicles would be an undue burden.